# How to get an X and Y axis Looking like this in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.5, axis-labels

Not asking anyone to do this for me. But I would like to be able to create something along the lines of this.... Excuse the drawing it isn't the best [image]

Currently my code is looking like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.grid()
plt.plot([0, 5 * np.cos(0)], [0, 5 * np.sin(0)])
plt.plot([0, -5 * np.cos(120)], [0, 5 * np.sin(120)])
plt.plot([0, 5 * np.cos(390)], [0, 5 * np.sin(390)])
plt.ylabel('Vectors')
plt.show()
```

This is the first thing I have tried to plot using a computer. I have a project i'm doing at college and I would rather plot it with a computer than do it by hand as I think it looks neater. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `plt.arrow(x, y, dx, dy)`-function for this.  It will make an arrow from `(x, y)` spanning a distance `(dx, dy)` in each direction.  Below is some example code, and I wrote it very "long", but when you understand how to use it I'm sure you can make it more compact if you like to.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.grid()
x = 0
y = 0
dx = 5 * np.cos(0)
dy = 5 * np.sin(0)
plt.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, head_width=0.1, head_length=0.5, fc='b', ec='b')

x = 0
y = 0
dx = 5 * np.cos(390)
dy = 5 * np.sin(390)
plt.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, head_width=0.1, head_length=0.5, fc='g', ec='g')

x = 0
y = 0
dx = -5 * np.cos(120)
dy = 5 * np.sin(120)
plt.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, head_width=0.1, head_length=0.5, fc='r', ec='r')
plt.ylabel('Vectors')
plt.xlim(-5.5, 5.5)
plt.ylim(-5.5, 5.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond this was really informative and much more helpful than the documentation for me :)